# Collision function Javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to detect when the player comes in contact with a platform, any idea why this is not working?

http://taffatech.com/Platformer.html

```
function checkCol()
{
for (var i=0;i<Platforms.length;i++)
{ 

if(Player.x > i.x && Player.x  < (i.x + i.width))
  {
    if(Player.y > i.y && Player.y < (i.y + i.height))
    {
    alert("hit");
    }
  }



}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i` is just a number. It doesn't have `width` and `height`. It looks like you meant to use `Platforms[i]` instead.

Comment: Thank you, this is what sleep deprivation does! I'll accept your answer when it lets me :)